# Asynchronous microservices in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, asynchronous, microservices

My task is to create two simple microservices for movie management. One of them is responsible for movies and another for reviews. I have to create function for adding reviews (reviews will be added after approve). To check review movie service should call approving (review) service asynchronously. This is my very first time with asynchronous methods and I am not sure how should I create it.

Below is my simple method from movie service to adding review.

```
public boolean addReviewForMovie(Review review, String movieId){
    Movie movie = movieRepository.findById(movieId);
    if(movie == null){
        return false;
    }
    review.setMovieId(movieId);
    return reviewService.addReview(review);
}
```

My approving algorithm is really simple - I want just to check couple of parameters. Here is my code.

```
public boolean addReview(Review review){
    if (review.getReviewContent().length() < 10
            || review.getReviewContent().length() > 250) {
        return false;
    }else if(review.getRating()<1d || review.getRating() > 10d){
        return false;
    }else if(review.getUserName().length() < 1
            || review.getUserName().length() > 15){
        return false;
    }
    review.setApproved(true);
    reviewRepository.save(review);
    return review.isApproved();
}
```

Could you please explain me how to create these methods asynchronous? I would appreciate if you send me some articles about it.

---

I refecator my code however I am not sure if this is the proper way. I exepect something else I guess.

Below is my method in movie service class. I use it to add review. This method should ask for asynchronous one.

```
public void addReviewForMovie(Review review){
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = reviewService.addReview(review);

    try {
       Boolean result = completableFuture.get();
       System.out.println(result);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is my approving method

```
public CompletableFuture addReview(Review review){
CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(()->{
    try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        boolean addedFlag = true;
        if (review.getReviewContent().length() < 10
                || review.getReviewContent().length() > 250) {
            addedFlag = false;
            completableFuture.complete(addedFlag);
        }else {
            review.setApproved(true);
            reviewRepository.save(review);
            completableFuture.complete(addedFlag);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
});
return completableFuture;
```

Is implementation correct? I thought that the idea is that the first method will not be waiting for the second one and send it back once the addReview will be complited.

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of ways to make them asynchronous. I think the question is too broad, however...

The first thing is to stop returning a boolean, otherwise the caller blocks while the method runs. In asynchronous code, the caller does not block, but is "called back" when the operation has completed.

You could return a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) which provides lots of ways to chain asynchronous actions.

```
public CompletableFuture addReview(Review review) {
   // TODO
}
```

Or make the caller provide a callback function which you will call when the result is ready.

```
public void addReview(Review review, Callback callback) {
   // TODO: Add the review and when finished
   callback.onSuccess();
}
```

Where `Callback` is an interface that would look something like this:

```
interface Callback {

    void onSuccess();

    void onFailure(Throwable cause);
}
```

Comment: So far I created simple methods without async thats why I return boolean. Is it wrong?

Comment: Performing the operation synchronously and returning its result is not async.

Comment: Do I need any spring annotation for your example?

Comment: No, this is plain java

Comment: I do not get it. If the method addReview would be void I will not return anything to the method addReviewForMovie so how could I know if magic happend? Moreover what does Callback inteface do? Could you please send me a full example?